# Node.js Export and use post request in another command line script

Tags: node.js, routes

i have a problem which i think it's a basic yet couldn't figure it out. I have a post request in a js file and i export it to app.js. And i have another js file which will be executed as command line script only. What i want is; using the same post internally by sending the body. I want to call the `post` and get the response in this file. Here is my code;

Customers.js;

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  //some work
  res.status(201).send(v_return);
});
module.exports.router = router;
```

Command-line.js;

```
const customer = require('./routes/customers')

//..some irrelevant code
//this is what i've tryed, i need to send cust[0] as req body
var res = customer.router.use(function(req,res){
        req.body=cust[0];                
    });
    console.log(res); //i need the response
//..some irrelevant code
```

Basically i need to make the post with `v_cust[0]` as body. And get the response. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I've create seperate function that takes body and do the work. Then i used it both post and command-line script. So i have a solution but still i don't know if i can make post request in the api. If there is an answer for it, i would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't see where you are making a post request. I only see you defining a route for handling post requests. Can you explain what you mean by "i need to make the post with v_cust[0] as body"?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I didn't write the app.js. There is `app.use` in there so i make post with the normal way. What i want is may be absurd but i just wonder if i can call the `post` like a function in another file without the url. Don't really know if it is possible.

Comment: ah, I see. Yes of course you could, you would just need to factor out the "some work" part into a separate function that is called in the post handler and that can be called directly. Calling the route handler itself probably doesn't make sense, or would be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Yes i did like you said, created seperate function and used it both :) I was just wondering if routing again would make sense, and it doesn't :) thaks for the reply